# expected='endstream' actual='' at offset 369250" rror occurs in some pdf

Tags: java, file, pdfbox, maven-dependency

I used 1.8.10-alfresco patched pdfbox version and I also tried 1.8.8.

And it will also work fine in some pdf.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
    <scope>1.8.10-alfresco-patched</scope>
</dependency>


    @Override
    public NodeRef appendPDF(NodeRef targetNodeRef, Map<String, Serializable> params) {
        PDDocument pdf = null;
        PDDocument pdfTarget = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        InputStream tis = null;
        File tempDir = null;
        ContentWriter writer = null;
        NodeRef destinationNode = null;

        try {
            NodeRef toAppend = (NodeRef) params.get(PARAM_TARGET_NODE);
            Boolean inplace = Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(params.get(PARAM_INPLACE)));
            ContentReader append = getReader(toAppend);
            is = append.getContentInputStream();

            ContentReader targetReader = getReader(targetNodeRef);
            System.out.println(targetNodeRef);
            tis = targetReader.getContentInputStream();
}
```

[ref File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ey4mmnwttgs05k3/file4.pdf?dl=0) this targetReader.getContentInputStream method will generate error.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample that causes the error?

Comment: Note that your dependency `scope` is an invalid string.

Comment: i added my code in that when i tried to get content it will throw error for some pdf .

Comment: No, no that simply will not do. You have to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: getContentInputStream() is not part of pdfbox

Comment: yes this error is generates  from input output stream not from pdfbox because it will occurs in some pdf. so how to resolve this kind of error.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "this error is generates from input output stream not from pdfbox because it will occurs in some pdf". Maybe share your PDF.

Comment: i have added my file to check

Comment: The file fails to be loaded with 1.8.16, but gets loaded with 2.0.21. That one has more repair features.

Comment: to use "import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility;" i need pdfbox version 1.8.8 so is there any way to use both version in project.

Comment: No. 2.0.21 has its own merger utility (which is much better). use `org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility`